# Resources$NotFoundException: If the resource you are trying to use is a vector resource, you may be referencing it in an unsupported way

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, android-vectordrawable, android-support-design

I'm getting the following error message

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: If the resource you are trying to use is a vector resource, you may be referencing it in an unsupported way. See AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled() for more info.
```

when im trying to set the following:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlight_background);
```

or

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.highlight_background));
```

I also tried using AppCompatImage. This happens on a device with Android 4.4.4. I've found another StackOverflow thread which provides to add

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

into a MyApplication class and

```
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

into the build.gradle. But the error still occurs. The drawable consists of the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

It's just a line to encircle an image. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your problem is android_color=attr/colorAccent"" line , see link below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`view.setBackgroundDrawable()` is deprecated, use 
`view.setBackgroundResource(int resId)` instead

For example,

```
yourview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlight_background);
```

and offcourse change your color value like this

```
android:color="@color/color_defined_in_colors_xml_file"
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: read the question carefully. He said "when im trying to set the following:
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlight_background);"

Comment: yeah sorry i edited the answer.

Comment: You and an_droid_dev are right. Changing android:color="?attr/colorAccent" to android:color="@color/colorAccent" did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can use imageView.setImageResource();